# Regex to match any integer greater than 1080?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex for any integer greater than 1080. So that the below numbers would match:

```
1081
1100
1111
1200
1280
4000
900000080
```

I came across this post: https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/regular-expression-regex-for-a-number-greater-than-1200/ but it didn't work for a number like 1300.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with regex is a lousy idea, but if you have a genuine need (like some software that only lets you use regex in filters), it's possible. Let's take it a step at a time, and let's work from larger numbers to smaller, because it makes it easier to think about:

- Any number with at least five digits is okay: `[1-9][0-9]{4,}`
- Any number 2,000 - 9,999 is okay: `[2-9][0-9]{3}`
- Any number 1,100 - 1,999 is okay: `1[1-9][0-9]{2}`
- Any number 1,090 - 1,099 is okay: `109[0-9]`
- Any number 1,081 - 1,089 is okay: `108[1-9]`
- Anything that's left is a number <= 1080, or not a number.

Putting it all together in reverse order, `^(?:108[1-9]|109[0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4,})$` should work. If you want to be a little more lax with number formats you could allow an optional leading `+` or any number of leading `0`s (but not include them in the part we're checking). That gets us

`^\+?0*(?:108[1-9]|109[0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4,})$`

Comment: Why put it in reverse order? Surely it's more efficient to match larger groups of numbers first?

Comment: @Nick readability. A decent regex engine should optimize it about the same regardless of what order it's written in. But you're welcome to do it in the order you like :)

Comment: It'd be interesting to benchmark the different regex engines to see if they were that smart...